# VBA macro stuck while running but OK while debugging - vlookup true

Tags: vba, excel, debugging

first I have to tell you that I'm a pretty new VBA coder and I started by recording a couple of years ago just for business needs.

A new part of my VBA project was very slow in looking up, so I learned how to use nested lookup with true and sorted database.

Everything worked fine in a separate macro, but when I included that macro in the main macro it happened to stuck without any error. So pressing ESC for a couple of times I understood that the code was stucking right after the command calculation set to automatic after the nested vlookups.

However, if I step the code while debugging, everything works perfectly!

I never bumped into such a problem and looking for something similar in the internet, I found too specific issues.

Thanks in advance for your kind contribution,

Here is the code:

```
Sheets("DB BOLLE").Select

Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=RC[1]&""_""&RC[2]&""_""&RC[3]&""_""&RC[4]&""_""&RC[5]&""_""&RC[6]&""_""&RC[7]"

numRows = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(numRows, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$I$1048576").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

Range("A1").AutoFilter

Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=RC[1]&""_""&RC[4]&""_""&RC[5]&""_""&RC[6]&""_""&RC[3]&""_""&RC[7]"

numRows = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(numRows, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheets("DB ORDINI-CLIENTI").Select

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DB ORDINI-CLIENTI").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DB ORDINI-CLIENTI").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range _
    ("A1:A1048576"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DB ORDINI-CLIENTI").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:BM1048576")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Range("A1").Select

Sheets("DB BOLLE").Select

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Range("K2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1,VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1:C14,14,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("K2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 11), Cells(numRows, 11)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("O2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1,VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1:C17,17,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("O2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(numRows, 15)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("S2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1,VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1:C20,20,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 19), Cells(numRows, 19)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("W2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1,VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1:C23,23,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("W2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 23), Cells(numRows, 23)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AA2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1,VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1:C26,26,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("AA2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 27), Cells(numRows, 27)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AE2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1,VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1:C29,29,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("AE2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 31), Cells(numRows, 31)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AI2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1,VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1:C32,32,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("AI2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 35), Cells(numRows, 35)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AM2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1,VLOOKUP(RC1,'DB ORDINI-CLIENTI'!C1:C7,7,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("AM2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 39), Cells(numRows, 39)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Range("K:K,O:O,S:S,W:W,AA:AA,AE:AE,AI:AI,AM:AM").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"

Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

...

Sheets("DB AVANZA").Select

Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=RC[1]&""_""&RC[7]&""_""&RC[6]&""_""&RC[2]&""_""&RC[3]&""_""&RC[4]&""_""&RC[58]&""_""&RC[8]"

numRows = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(numRows, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Columns("A:A").Copy
Columns("A:A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DB AVANZA").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DB AVANZA").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A2:A1048576"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DB AVANZA").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:BG1048576")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

Range("A1").Select

Sheets("DB BOLLE").Select

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Range("J2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C10,10,TRUE),""-""))"

numRows = Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("J2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 10), Cells(numRows, 10)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=""-"",""NESSUNA SCADENZA"",IF(RC[-2]=""-"",""AVANZ. NON REG."",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))="""",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_" & _
    "1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-""))="""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(TODAY(),5)),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-"")),5))),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C" & _
    "1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))))))" & _
    ""

Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 12), Cells(numRows, 12)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("M2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&" & _
    """_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))))),""-"",RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1" & _
    ",1,TRUE)=RC1&""_1"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_1"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE)))))" & _
    ""

Range("M2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 13), Cells(numRows, 13)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C10,10,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("N2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 14), Cells(numRows, 14)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("P2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=""-"",""NESSUNA SCADENZA"",IF(RC[-2]=""-"",""AVANZ. NON REG."",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))="""",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_" & _
    "2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-""))="""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(TODAY(),3)),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-"")),3))),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C" & _
    "1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))))))" & _
    ""

Range("P2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 16), Cells(numRows, 16)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("Q2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&" & _
    """_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))))),""-"",RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1" & _
    ",1,TRUE)=RC1&""_2"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_2"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE)))))" & _
    ""

Range("Q2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 17), Cells(numRows, 17)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("R2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C10,10,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("R2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 18), Cells(numRows, 18)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("T2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=""-"",""NESSUNA SCADENZA"",IF(RC[-2]=""-"",""AVANZ. NON REG."",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))="""",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_" & _
    "3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-""))="""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(TODAY(),3)),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-"")),3))),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C" & _
    "1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))))))" & _
    ""

Range("T2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 20), Cells(numRows, 20)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("U2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&" & _
    """_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))))),""-"",RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1" & _
    ",1,TRUE)=RC1&""_3"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_3"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE)))))" & _
    ""

Range("U2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 21), Cells(numRows, 21)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("V2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C10,10,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("V2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 22), Cells(numRows, 22)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("X2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=""-"",""NESSUNA SCADENZA"",IF(RC[-2]=""-"",""AVANZ. NON REG."",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))="""",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_" & _
    "4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-""))="""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(TODAY(),8)),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-"")),8))),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C" & _
    "1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))))))" & _
    ""

Range("X2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 24), Cells(numRows, 24)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("Y2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&" & _
    """_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))))),""-"",RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1" & _
    ",1,TRUE)=RC1&""_4"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_4"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE)))))" & _
    ""

Range("Y2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 25), Cells(numRows, 25)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("Z2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C10,10,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("Z2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 26), Cells(numRows, 26)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AB2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=""-"",""NESSUNA SCADENZA"",IF(RC[-2]=""-"",""AVANZ. NON REG."",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))="""",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_" & _
    "6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-""))="""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(TODAY(),8)),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-"")),8))),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C" & _
    "1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))))))" & _
    ""

Range("AB2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 28), Cells(numRows, 28)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AC2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&" & _
    """_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))))),""-"",RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1" & _
    ",1,TRUE)=RC1&""_6"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_6"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE)))))" & _
    ""

Range("AC2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 29), Cells(numRows, 29)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AD2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C10,10,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("AD2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 30), Cells(numRows, 30)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AF2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=""-"",""NESSUNA SCADENZA"",IF(RC[-2]=""-"",""AVANZ. NON REG."",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))="""",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_" & _
    "7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-""))="""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(TODAY(),5)),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-"")),5))),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C" & _
    "1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))))))" & _
    ""

Range("AF2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 32), Cells(numRows, 32)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AG2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&" & _
    """_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))))),""-"",RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1" & _
    ",1,TRUE)=RC1&""_7"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_7"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE)))))" & _
    ""

Range("AG2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 33), Cells(numRows, 33)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AH2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C10,10,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("AH2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 34), Cells(numRows, 34)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AJ2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=""-"",""NESSUNA SCADENZA"",IF(RC[-2]=""-"",""AVANZ. NON REG."",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))="""",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_" & _
    "8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-""))="""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(TODAY(),3)),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-"")),3))),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C" & _
    "1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))))))" & _
    ""

Range("AJ2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 36), Cells(numRows, 36)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AK2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&" & _
    """_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))))),""-"",RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1" & _
    ",1,TRUE)=RC1&""_8"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_8"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE)))))" & _
    ""

Range("AK2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 37), Cells(numRows, 37)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AL2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C10,10,TRUE),""-""))"

Range("AL2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 38), Cells(numRows, 38)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AN2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(RC[-1]=""-"",""NESSUNA SCADENZA"",IF(RC[-2]=""-"",""AVANZ. NON REG."",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))="""",IF(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_" & _
    "9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-""))="""",NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(TODAY(),2)),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],WORKDAY(IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C11,11,TRUE),""-"")),2))),NETWORKDAYS(RC[-1],IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C" & _
    "1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C12,12,TRUE),""-""))))))" & _
    ""

Range("AN2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 40), Cells(numRows, 40)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Range("AO2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(ISERROR(RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&" & _
    """_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))))),""-"",RC[-1]*IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)),""-"",IF(ISERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE))),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1,1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C15,15,TRUE)),IF(VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1" & _
    ",1,TRUE)=RC1&""_9"",VLOOKUP(RC1&""_9"",'DB AVANZA'!C1:C14,14,TRUE)))))" & _
    ""

Range("AO2").AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, 41), Cells(numRows, 41)), Type:=xlFillDefault

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Columns("J:AO").Copy
Columns("J:AO").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Cheers

Comment: without posting your code we can do nothing...

Comment: Without seeing the code nobody can tell you what you did wrong. So please [edit] your question and add the code formatted as codeblock (with 4 spaces indentation).

Comment: the whole code you mean?

Comment: It has been tough to squeeze the most important part of the code in the limited character number, but I hope I did it

Comment: I read that already, but I really don't know where the problem is...

Comment: I had similar issues when I did not follow the [Best Practices Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices). (1) [Avoid using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) (2) [Never assume the worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet) (3) [Avoid using activecell or activesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/7264/avoid-using-activecell-or-activesheet-in-excel).

Comment: Follow these 3 guides and I'm pretty sure your issues are gone. This is probably only a `.Select` issue which doesn't occur when Excel has enough time in step-by-step debug mode. And will not occur if you use well defined worksheets instead of active worksheet.

Comment: @Peh, so you think it is not related to the nested vlookups calculated all at the same time?
Because the thing it seems too weird to me is that a couple of time also running the entire macro it didn't stuck at all. But after a while, without touching the code, it happened all of a sudden that the code was stucking and now it is like this.

Comment: "*calculated all at the same time*": Excel VBA can't multithread so everything is done sequently one after another. And yes I still think this is a `.Select`/`ActiveSheet` issue. Follow the Best Practices Guide (it's a good idea anyway so you should always follow it!) and report if your issues are gone.

Comment: I actually insert a save command just before the tough macro and now everything is working perfectly everytime